# Alignment within enumerate environment and mhchem

Tags: align, enumerate, mhchem

I'm trying to create a question sheet for pupils in which they fill out the proton and atomic numbers of elements after they undergo radioactive decay.

I have succeeded in using the mhchem environment and tikz to produce the following worksheet:

[image]

using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand\isotope{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, baseline=-4pt]
\draw (0,0.1) rectangle (1.5,1.1)
(0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,-1.1)
(1.7,-1.1) rectangle (3.8,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{huge}
\item $\!\begin{aligned}[t] 
 \ce{^213_90Th -> ^4_2\alpha{} + & \isotope} \\
 \end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t] 
 \ce{^194_86Rn -> ^4_2\alpha{} + & \isotope} \\
 \end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t] 
 \ce{^217_91Pa -> ^4_2\alpha{} + &  \isotope} \\
 \end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t] 
 \ce{^221_90Th -> ^4_2\alpha{} + & \isotope} 
 \end{aligned}$
  \end{huge}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

However, notice how the boxes do not align with each other, which drives me crazy.

I have tried to use the align* environment with the enumerate environment to no avail.

My latest attempt is with the aligned[t] environment but as you can see this hasn't fixed the problem.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated answer, without automagic isotopes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand\isotope{
\medskip\par
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, baseline=-4pt]
\draw (0,0.1) rectangle (1.5,1.1)
(0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,-1.1)
(1.7,-1.1) rectangle (3.8,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}


\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rows}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\stepcounter{rows}}l<{\arabic{rows}.}}
\newcolumntype{A}{c<{\ce{->}}}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ClAll}
  & \ce{^213_90Th} &  &  \ce{^4_2\alpha{}}  &  + \isotope \\
  & \ce{^194_86Rn} &  &  \ce{^4_2\alpha{}}  &  + \isotope \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]

Explanation: we use a `tabular` instead of an `enumerate` to achieve alignment. The counter is generated by a special column type `C`, which augments a counter and typesets the value; within the table, you don't have to fill in anything. We use a similar trick for the reaction arrow; it is provided by a custom `A` column type, so that all you have to do is to insert an empty table cell.

The problem posed is also a nice opportunity to showcase Martin Scharrer's `collcell` package, which provides an easy way to apply a macro to the contents of each table cell. Here, we define an `E` column type that applies `mhchem`s `\ce` macro to each cell. Moreover, we create another `I` column type that populates each cell with the custom-defined `\isotope` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand\isotope{
\medskip\par
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, baseline=-4pt]
\draw (0,0.1) rectangle (1.5,1.1)
(0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,-1.1)
(1.7,-1.1) rectangle (3.8,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}


\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rows}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\stepcounter{rows}}l<{\arabic{rows}.}}
\newcolumntype{A}{c<{\ce{->}}}
\newcolumntype{I}{l<{+ \isotope}}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\ce}l<{\endcollectcell}}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{CEAEI}
  & ^213_90Th &  &  ^4_2\alpha  &  \\
  & ^194_86Rn &  &  ^4_2\alpha  &  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the very same as shown above.

Comment: This is good, but I have other functions similar to isotope that take arguments (such as the proton number but leave the atomic symbol and mass number empty), so I need the \isotope command not to be a column type, and it's difficult to see how to incorporate that into your solution.

Comment: see updated answer - just use a plain l, c or r column and type in the `\isotope` macros manually.

Answer (score 4):

I propose a solution with the `listliketab` package, in the place of a real list. The ‘items’ can be cross-referenced.

I also defined a `\myisotope` command, which doesn't require `tikz`, but simply relies on `hhline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array, hhline, enumitem, listliketab}

\newcommand\isotope{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, baseline=-4pt]
\draw (0,0.1) rectangle (1.5,1.1)
(0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,-1.1)
(1.7,-1.1) rectangle (3.8,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand\myisotope{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}\setlength\extrarowheight{12pt}\begin{tabular}{|p{10pt}||p{18pt}|}\hhline{-||-}& \\\hhline{:=:|~|} & \\\hhline{|-||-|}\end{tabular}}%&

\begin{document}

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.}
\begin{tabular}{Lr@{}l}
\tabitem\label{th} & \ce{^213_90Th -> ^4_2\alpha{} +} & \myisotope\\[20pt]
\tabitem & \ce{^194_86Rn -> ^4_2\alpha{} +} & \myisotope\\[20pt]
\tabitem & \ce{^217_91Pa -> ^4_2\alpha{} +} & \myisotope \\[20pt]
\tabitem & \ce{^221_90Th -> ^4_2\alpha{} +} & \myisotope
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

Reaction \ref{th}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what `listliketab` actually does for you here? I see you still generate the item labels with a custom counter. Is it just for the sake of cross-referencing?

Comment: Not only: the spacing is formatted like a true enumerate. Actually, it emulates  enumerate within a table, defining a new column type. I guess one could automate the whole process in the preamble, initialising a counter in the background, so that one would only  see a tabular and the `\tabitem` commands.